# Remove different type of characters form DataFrame column

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I have the following column in a DataFrame

```
0      EUR/USD
1      GBP/USD
2      USD/JPY
3      USD/CHF
4      AUD/USD
5      USD/CAD
6      NZD/USD
7      USD/ZAR
8      USD/TRY
9      BTC/USD
10     USD/MXN
11     USD/PLN
12     USD/SEK
13     USD/SGD
14     USD/DKK
```

I need to remove every / and every USD. To have this format:

```
0      EUR
1      GBP
2      JPY
3      CHF
4      AUD
5      CAD
6      NZD
7      ZAR
8      TRY
9      BTC
10     MXN
11     PLN
12     SEK
13     SGD
14     DKK
```

I was able to do this by

```
ListCurrencies['Pair'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'[^\w]',value=r'')
ListCurrencies['Pair'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'USD',value=r'')`
```

How can I combine those two arguments in a single line of code?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str.replace` with the regex pattern `/USD|USD/`:

```
In [180]: df['col'].str.replace(r'/USD|USD/', '')
Out[180]: 
0     EUR
1     GBP
2     JPY
3     CHF
4     AUD
5     CAD
6     NZD
7     ZAR
8     TRY
9     BTC
10    MXN
11    PLN
12    SEK
13    SGD
14    DKK
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Note, however, that if these represent foreign exchange rates, the order
matters. `x EUR/USD` indicates `x` USD equals 1 EUR. While `x USD/EUR` indicates
1 USD = `x` EUR. If you eliminate the `USD/` or `/USD`, it may no longer be
clear what associated values mean.